# In a game built with purely functional programming, how could one player do damage (alter state) of another player?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I know very little about functional programming other than the idea of pure functions.  In John Carmack's 2013 Quakecon talk he mentioned one of the questions often asked about functional programming as related to games: how do you fire a gun and do damage to another player if you don't have access to state? (paraphrased)  In mentioned something about an event system, which I didn't quite understand, since it seems to me an event system would still need state?

How would one accomplish this in a purely functional language?

Comment: In Haskell, you can use a State monad.

Comment: Have you seen the myriad other questions about FP and state? Some of them are even listed to the right under "Related". TL;DR - There's state alright, just no mutable state. (The `State` monad mentioned above isn't magic, it's just thirty lines of library code.)

Comment: Using "State monad" (googlable), yes. Basically it is just `type State s a = s -> (a, s)` with `Monad` & co instances. For a pure "game" example see http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html.

Comment: We had a meetup recently with a talk about functional game programming. Here is the youtube vid: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYj5GOneM4k.  Here is the meetup link with slides, github link, etc: http://www.meetup.com/Game-Technology-Brisbane/events/139193912/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To repeat one of my favorite quotes

> ... takes in the state of the world and returns a new world, thus remaining pure.

This was talking about Clean, a cousin of Haskell but it's still related. The gist of it is, you're right, you need some kind of state, but it doesn't have to be mutable. Consider

```
myFun :: StateOfTheWorld -> a -> (StateOfTheWorld, b)
```

so we don't modify the state, we just produce a new one. This is referentially transparent, since given the same state of the world and the same action, you'll get the same thing back.

For you you might have something like

```
 killPlayer :: Game -> Event -> Game
 killPlayer g (Kill x) = g { isDead = x : isDead g }
```

which is just using functional updates for records. This is a bit klunky, so we might do something like

```
 killPlayer :: Game -> Event -> Action
 killPlayer (PlayerDamaged x amount) = if playerHealth g x <= amount
                                       then KillPlayer x
                                       else ReduceHealth x amount
```

So we just return the differences, not the full game state.

This works, but is ugly. So we prettify this with `do` notation and Control.Monad.State. This sounds scary but it's exactly what we were doing above, just with a bit more syntactic abstraction. In fact, this is what `IO` is on GHC as well. I don't know if you've learned about Monads, but the State monad is often the motivating example.

Finally to get back to games, many of the gameframeworks I've seen are like this: piles of things listening to events and then suggesting some small incremental change to the game state and returning the different, finally the framework itself makes the appropriate openGL calls or whatever to implement those changes.

Answer (score 2):

State is just a set of values in the environment. Haskell makes you treat your environment explicitly, so we can call it `Env`. We create new ones

```
letThereBeLight :: Env
letThereBeLight = Env { personHealth = 100 }
```

And modify them

```
shootEmUp :: Env -> Env
shootEmUp oldEnv = oldEnv { personHealth = personHealth oldEnv - 30 }
```

Types like `Env -> Env` are called `Endo Env` in that you apply them end-to-end to make many changes to the state.

```
assassinate = shootEmUp . shootEmUp . shootEmUp . shootEmUp
```

If you want to do more than *just* modify a state you need to sequence other values alongside your state `Endo`. Instead of looking like `Env -> Env` you begin to see `Env -> (Env, a)` where `a` models your other data flow and build from there. This thing is known as the state Monad because there are some highly clever ways to make manipulating these two information flows together quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

To support my comment, here is an example adapted from http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- * Our homegrown state monad (use @State@ from the MTL package in production).

-- | @State@ is a function (lets call it "state-updater") which "updates" a
-- state @s@ and returns some associated result @r@.
newtype State s r = State { run :: s -> (r, s) }

-- | This state-updater function is a monad.
instance Monad (State s) where

  -- | Build a state-updater which returns @x@ and don't change the state.
  return x = State $ \st -> (x, st)

  -- | From a state-updater @m@ and a function @f@ which returns a state-updater
  -- we can build a new (lazy) state-updater by performing update actions of this two
  -- state-updaters.
  m >>= f = State $ \st -> let (x, st') = run m st in run (f x) st'

-- | Simply swap the state.
put :: s -> State s ()
put st = State $ const ((), st)

-- | Get the current state as a result of this state-updater.
get :: State r r
get = State $ \st -> (st, st)

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- * An example.

-- | Player with its health.
newtype Player = Player { _health :: Int } deriving ( Show )

-- | Game of two players.
data Game = Game { _player1 :: !Player, _player2  :: !Player } deriving ( Show )

-- | Starting from weak and strong players.
initialState :: Game
initialState = Game (Player 10) (Player 20)

-- | First player hit second.
hit12 :: State Game ()
hit12 = do
  g@(Game _ p2@(Player health)) <- get
  put g { _player2 = p2 { _health = health - 1 } }

-- | Second player hit first.
hit21 :: State Game ()
hit21 = do
  g@(Game p1@(Player health) _) <- get
  put g { _player1 = p1 { _health = health - 1 } }

-- | Test it.
test :: ((), Game)
test = run (do { hit12; hit12; hit12; hit21 }) initialState
-- 
-- initialState
-- =>
-- Game {_player1 = Player {_health = 10}, _player2 = Player {_health = 20}}
-- 
-- snd test
-- =>
-- Game {_player1 = Player {_health = 9}, _player2 = Player {_health = 17}}
--
```

[Lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) allow to write

```
hit12 = player2.health -= 1

hit21 = player1.health -= 1
```

[State transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) (which you should use anyway) allows to mix another monad (like `IO`) to `State`, but basically it's all pure and works like this:

> ... takes in the state of the world and returns a new world, thus
>   remaining pure.

as another comment quoted.